# DDD - clean architecture vs clear workflow

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

We are writing in a DDD *manner*, meaning we do not "follow DDD as a bible" but rather make use of the benefits it offers, and bend it when it forces us to do stuff thats not "common sense" for us  - after all one of DDD's main point is that the code stays close to the real life use cases.

And here is one place where the techniquetook us a little off track:

**Adding an item to a basket user story:** (I'm keeping it short here...)

"when a customer adds an item to the basket, if sale is over limit (1000$), user will get a "Maximum sale is 1000$" popup
If this item appears in the basket more times than allowed user will get a "Product exceeded max amount allowed in one order" popup
And the item does not exist in the stock user will get a "Product XXX is out of stock" popup
If all terms are ok, add the item to the basket"

Application code may look like this:

```
func basketapp.AddItem(basketId, productId, quantity){

   myBasket := BasketRepo.LoadByID(basketId)      //load the basket
   Product := ProductService.GetByID(productId)   //get the requested product 
   myBasket.AddItem(Product, quantity)            //runs internal domain business logic to add the item
   BasketRepo.Save(basketId, myBasket)            //Persist/add event source
}
```

Where domain business logic would look like this:

```
func model.basket.AddItem(product, quantity){
   if basket.total() > maxTotalPerBasket {
       return maxItemsPerBasketExceededError
   }

   if basket.CountItem(product.id) > product.MaxRepeatsPerSale {
       return productCountLimitExceededError
   }
   .....
   item := newBasketItem(product, quantity ....)
    basket.Items.Append(item)
}
```

The problem starts when I wish to validate the product is in stock after the simple validations
To the human (customer, product manager developer) mind, its another validation, so writing this as the user story suggests:

```
func model.basket.AddItem(product, quantity){
   if basket.total() > maxTotalPerBasket {
       return maxItemsPerBasketExceededError
   }
 
   if basket.CountItem(product.id) > product.MaxRepeatsPerSale {
       return productCountLimitExceededError
   }
        
   if !inventoryService.exists(product.Id,storeId ){
       return productNotInInventoryError
   }
        
   item := newBasketItem(product, quantity ....)

   basket.Items.Append(item)
}
```

But according the DDD concepts, model does not call another service (even not an injected scheme),

So the extra code would be a part of the app layer, and I would need to split model.AddItem in this manner:

```
func basketapp.AddItem(basketId, productId, quantity){

   myBasket := BasketRepo.LoadByID(basketId)        
   Product := ProductService.GetByID(productId)     
   //myBasket.AddItem(Product, quantity)            
        
        
   if !myBasket.ValidateItem(Product, quantity){    //Where ValidateItem is the model basket.total()+basket.CountItem code
      return ...
   } else if !StockLevelService.exists(productId, storeId ){
      return ...
   }
   myBasket.AddItem(Product, quantity)  //leaving lines from model.Additem after validation
        
          
   BasketRepo.Save(basketId, myBasket)         
        
}
```

Its cleaner code wise, but now the user story needs to change (and for that - people writing this user story should understand that architecture wise stockLevel is something done in a different service/domain".

We had some other mutations of this idea, yet we cant find a way that will "play by the technical rules" on the one hand, and "will read as the user story" on the other (and of course need to consider everyone on the team will easily understand where is the right place for everything, so we will not find mixed approaches and need to fix upon code review... as well as quickly know where to go when debugging each part etc)

Ideas are welcome :)

Comment: You can pass the service to check as an argument to the AR method.

Comment: `!StockLevelService.exists` uses `storedid`: where in the architecture does that come from? (it's missing from your pseudo-code)

Comment: the @plalx comment is a good point but. I see another problem though: When you add the Item to your basket, inventory should change its product avaliability status. If this can happen asynchronlously, maybe you don't need to interact with the inventory, sending a domain event (and receiving one in case of unavaliability) could work. Otherwise you could implment a domain service interface and inject it in AR, it will "commit" an inventory product if avaliable

Answer (score 0):

> we cant find a way that will "play by the technical rules" on the one hand, and "will read as the user story" on the other

Not your fault -- the literature is pretty miserable.

Domain models are primarily a bookkeeping device; their responsibility is manipulating information, in particular the manipulation of information in local memory.

Problem: it isn't always the case that the information you want is local.  Sometimes you need to ask somebody else for the information that you need.

In your specific case, the local information would include the data structure of the basket model, and the local arguments that had been passed to the application; the problem comes from things like `inStock?`, which requires information that you don't have locally.

So we normally need a piece of plumbing to get that information.  Here `StockLevelService::exists` serves as an example - you pass it some local information, it gives you back a local copy of an answer that lives somewhere else.

At this point, you've got two possible patterns that will allow you to get the copy of the information that you need without introducing a big snarl of dependencies.

On answer is to pass that piece of plumbing into the model, so that the model can invoke it to get the copy of the information that it needs

```
func model.basket.AddItem(product, quantity, inventoryService){ 
   // ...
   if !inventoryService.exists(product.Id,storeId ){
       return productNotInInventoryError
   }
   // ...
```

An alternative is to invoke the plumbing in the application code, and pass the answer into the domain model

```
func basketapp.AddItem(basketId, productId, quantity){

   myBasket := BasketRepo.LoadByID(basketId)      //load the basket
   Product := ProductService.GetByID(productId)   //get the requested product 


   myBasket.AddItem(Product, quantity, inventoryService.exists(Product, quantity))            //runs internal domain business logic to add the item
   BasketRepo.Save(basketId, myBasket)            //Persist/add event source
}
```

> Design is what we do to get more of what we want than we would get by just doing it.

Which of these is "better" is going to depend a lot on the "what we want" that you want more of.  The second design is simpler (the domain model is isolated from the problem of handling errors), but it isn't necessarily *easier*.

The difference in the two approaches really starts to stand out when you don't know ahead of time what arguments to use when fetching the remote information, or when/if it should be called, and so on.  Or when, in the event of failure, you are supposed to save the progress you have made so far, rather than just exploding and rolling everything back.

Reviewing these two talks may help:

- Gary Bernhardt: [Boundaries](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries)
- Cory Benfield: [Building Protocol Libraries the Right Way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cC3_jGwl_U)

Comment: This helped in: 
1. Understanding there is no "one answer" that I'm missing
2. mapping the options pros and cons :
    a. simpler design vs easier (not always the same)
    b. pass ready to use values or dependencies as arguments
    c. Is fetching those values always necessary or only based on other logic (and can this logic be on app or must it be on model not to over complicate stuff) 
    d. if you do call a dependency on model, how do you handle errors in a standard manner
    e. If you do handle the error in model, how do single app how to proceed ?